# Join of two data.tables fails

Tags: r, join, data.table, lookup

I am trying to use a data table as a lookup table:

```
> (dt <- data.table(myid=rep(11:12,3),zz=1:6,key=c("myid","zz")))
   myid zz
1:   11  1
2:   11  3
3:   11  5
4:   12  2
5:   12  4
6:   12  6
> (id2name <- data.table(id=11:14,name=letters[1:4],key="id"))
   id name
1: 11    a
2: 12    b
3: 13    c
4: 14    d
```

What I want is

```
> (res <- data.table(myid=rep(11:12,3),zz=1:6,name=rep(letters[1:2],3),key=c("myid","zz")))
   myid zz name
1:   11  1    a
2:   11  3    a
3:   11  5    a
4:   12  2    b
5:   12  4    b
6:   12  6    b
```

however, the join I tried failed:

```
> dt[id2name]
Starting binary search ...done in 0 secs
Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian) NULL else as.integer(max(nrow(x),  : 
  Join results in 8 rows; more than 6 = max(nrow(x),nrow(i)). Check for duplicate key values in i, each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try including `j` and dropping `by` (by-without-by) so that j runs for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and datatable-help for advice.
Calls: [ -> [.data.table -> vecseq
```

what am I doing wrong?

PS. I am amenable to any alternative way to get the results; what is the most idiomatic way to do what I want (`dt` must still be a `data.table`, but `id2name` can be anything mapping int to something else - as long as the int is not assumed to be a vector index).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
> dt[id2name, allow.cartesian=T, nomatch=0]
   myid zz name
1:   11  1    a
2:   11  3    a
3:   11  5    a
4:   12  2    b
5:   12  4    b
6:   12  6    b
```

`data.table` is trying to save you from yourself in case you had an unintentional join on keys with duplicate values.  Note that the error message (eventually) tells you what to do if you're sure you know what you're doing.

Alternatively:

```
> id2name[dt]
   id name zz
1: 11    a  1
2: 11    a  3
3: 11    a  5
4: 12    b  2
5: 12    b  4
6: 12    b  6
```

Comment: Note that the key is unique in the second table (`I=id2name`) so no cartesian product is necessary

Comment: @sds, I think the check that `data.table` carries out only compares the result of the join to the length of the inner table, it doesn't actually figure out whether it is a cartesian join or not.  So the argument name isn't perfect.

Comment: thanks, I wonder if `name` can be inserted into `dt` using `:=`?

Comment: @sds, read the explanation for `allow.cartesian` in `?data.table`. I think that'll clear up many things. The word *cartesian* is used loosely here.

Comment: @sds `dt[id2name, name := i.name, allow.cartesian = T]`

Comment: @eddi, thanks for the reminder on `i.`; keep forgetting about it.

Comment: @BrodieG fwiw in this case, since there is no `name` in the original table it will work without `i.` as well, it's just clearer and more generalizable this way